# Explanation of Self-healing property of CBC (Cipher Block Chaining)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cbc-mode

**Wikipedia**:

> CBC mode has the self-healing property:  if one block of the cipher is
>   altered, the error propagates for at most two blocks.

**Made up Example:**

Let the block size be 64 bits. The original plaintext is:

```
3231343336353837  3231343336353837  3231343336353837  • • •
```

The correct cipher text is:

```
ef7c4bb2b4ce6f3b  f6266e3a97af0e2c  746ab9a6308f4256 • • •
```

If the ciphertext is corrupted, with the byte `'0x4b'` changed to `'0x4c'`:

```
ef7c4cb2b4ce6f3b  f6266e3a97af0e2c  746ab9a6308f4256  • • •
```

Then it is decrypted to:

```
efca61e19f4836f1  3231333336353837  3231343336353837  • • •
```

**Question:**

I am having hard time understanding the self-healing property of CBC (Cipher Block Chaining), I thought that a made up example might help but I am now more confused. Any help would be great.

Comment: Your question would be even better, if you would provide the code to generate your example, including the IV and key, so others would know how to reproduce your example. I assume you have used DES?

Comment: @Perseids Yes. I did use DES.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Personally, I find the decryption graphics very helpful for such kind of questions. [From the Wikipedia (public domain image)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CBC_decryption.svg):

[image: Original CBC decryption]

Now let's add some corruption:

[image: Corrupted CBC decryption]

The red dots represent partial corrupted inputs, while the solid red line represents complete block corruption.

**Some notation before we start**: I'll number the original plaintext blocks as `p1` through `p3`, the corrupted ones as `p1'` through `p3'`, the correct ciphertext blocks as `c1` through `c3` and the corrupted ones as `c1'` through `c3'`:

```
3231343336353837  3231343336353837  3231343336353837  • • •
       p1                p2                 p3

ef7c4bb2b4ce6f3b  f6266e3a97af0e2c  746ab9a6308f4256  • • •
       c1                c2                 c3

ef7c4cb2b4ce6f3b  f6266e3a97af0e2c  746ab9a6308f4256  • • •
       c1'               c2'=c3             c3'=c3

efca61e19f4836f1  3231333336353837  3231343336353837  • • •
       p1'               p2'                p3'=p3
```

There is also some `IV` that you have not given in your example.

**Let's take a look at the first block**: Three bits in the input of the block cipher are changed (`0x4b ^ 0x4c = 0x07 = 4+2+1`). As a block cipher is designed to be a pseudo random permutation - that is a bijective function being indistinguishable from a random function (without knowledge of the key `k`) - we get a completely (pseudo) random block as output of the decryption function:

```
    dec(      c1        ,k) =         p1       XOR IV
<=> dec(ef7c4bb2b4ce6f3b,k) = 3231343336353837 XOR IV
    dec(      c1'       ,k) =         p1'      XOR IV
<=> dec(ef7c4cb2b4ce6f3b,k) = efca61e19f4836f1 XOR IV
```

As a next step the IV is XORed, so we end up with

```
    dec(      c1        ,k) XOR IV =         p1       
<=> dec(ef7c4bb2b4ce6f3b,k) XOR IV = 3231343336353837 
    dec(      c1'       ,k) XOR IV =         p1'      
<=> dec(ef7c4cb2b4ce6f3b,k) XOR IV = efca61e19f4836f1
```

which shows that the whole block was destroyed (complete red block at the bottom).

**Now, on to the second block**: We start again by decrypting the ciphertext block, which works fine as no corruption has occurred in the block:

```
    dec(      c2        ,k) =         p2       XOR         c1
<=> dec(f6266e3a97af0e2c,k) = 3231343336353837 XOR ef7c4bb2b4ce6f3b
                                                    ^
```

Notice that this formula uses non-corrupted blocks everywhere. As a reminder, this block was generated like this during encryption:

```
             c2      = enc(        p2       XOR         c1      ,k)
<=> f6266e3a97af0e2c = enc(3231343336353837 XOR ef7c4bb2b4ce6f3b,k)
```

The next step is again the application of the XOR with the previous block (this time not the IV, but c1'). This previous block c1' is corrupted:

```
    dec(      c2        ,k) XOR       c1'        =         p2       XOR         c1       XOR        c1'
<=> dec(f6266e3a97af0e2c,k) XOR ef7c4cb2b4ce6f3b = 3231343336353837 XOR ef7c4bb2b4ce6f3b XOR ef7c4cb2b4ce6f3b
```

Now we can actually calculate `c1 XOR c1'` (the error) as `c1 XOR c1' = 0000007000000000` and replace that everywhere:

```
    dec(      c2        ,k) XOR       c1'        =         p2       XOR 0000007000000000
<=> dec(f6266e3a97af0e2c,k) XOR ef7c4cb2b4ce6f3b = 3231343336353837 XOR 0000007000000000
```

And at last simplify `p2 XOR 0000007000000000 = p2'`:

```
    dec(      c2        ,k) XOR       c1'        =         p2'      
<=> dec(f6266e3a97af0e2c,k) XOR ef7c4cb2b4ce6f3b = 3231333336353837
```

You see that the original corruption (`0x07`) to the first ciphertext block `c1'` is transferred verbatim to the the second plaintext block `p2'`, but it remains otherwise intact (as is visualized by a mostly white block in the graphic, with a single square being red). This peculiar property of CBC can lead to attacks against real world systems, like [padding oracle attacks](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2013/a-padding-oracle-example).

**The third block is boring as hell:** No inputs to the decryption and XOR have changed, thus `p1=p1'` and everything is fine there.

Answer (score 2):

When decrypting in **CBC mode** a block is decrypted by first deciphering the block in question using the key, and then XOR it with the previous block in the ciphertext. Take a look at the **CBC mode** drawing on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29)

As you only need the current and previous block for decryptin in CBC mode, the effect of a changed byte in the ciphertext, would only affect the block it's in, and the following block (if that exists).